# How to save two items which comes with pushNotification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rx-swift

1)When notification comes,i need to save data from AnyHashable("data") "amount" and "inBalance"?

2)From server comes two pushes first push with "message",second "nil message body".There when nil message comes i need to silent it? 
How i can save it?
I'm using xCode 10.2.1

my code for pushNotification.swift looks like:

```
enum PillikanRemoteNotification:Int {
    case empty
    case notification = 2
    case news = 3
}

class PushManagerNotification {
    func convert(with value: [AnyHashable: Any], and state: PushNotificationAction) {
        guard let json = value as? [String: AnyObject], !json.isEmpty else { return }
        guard let jsonString = value["data"] as? String, !jsonString.isEmpty else { return }
        guard let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
        guard let rawDictionary = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .mutableLeaves) else { return }
        guard let dictionary = rawDictionary as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
        guard let actionType = dictionary["action"] as? String, let action = Int(actionType) else { return }
        guard let notificationType = PillikanRemoteNotification(rawValue: action) else { return }
        guard let messageBody = dictionary["msg"] as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }

        if state == .show {
            showBadges(dictionary: messageBody)
            return
        }

        switch notificationType {
        case .notification:
            showNotification(dictionary: messageBody)
            break
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private func showBadges(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) {
        guard let badgeMessage = dictionary["badges"] as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
        guard let badges = Badges(JSON: badgeMessage) else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.notificationBadgesForNotification = badges.notifications
        UIApplication.shared.notificationBadgesForNews = badges.news
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badges.news + badges.notifications
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .badges, object: badges)
    }

    private func showNotification(dictionary: [String:AnyObject]) {
        if let message = NotificationEntity(JSON: dictionary) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .notification, object: message);
        }
    }

extension Notification.Name {
    static let empty = Notification.Name("empty");
    static let notification = Notification.Name("notification");
    static let news = Notification.Name("news");
    static let badges = Notification.Name("badges")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here you can see, How I‘m taking token from AnyHashable and then take a specific value from it.

Try this code. It will help you out.

```
if(response.result.isSuccess){
       let data = response.result.value
          print(data!)
            if (data?.contains("access_token"))!{
                var dictonary:NSDictionary?
                    if let data = data!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                       do {
                            dictonary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:AnyObject] as NSDictionary?

                                UserDefaults.standard.set(dictonary!["access_token"]!, forKey: "token")


                            }catch let error as NSError {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        }
                     }
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

inside the `didReceive` function use this :

```
let amount =  userInfo["data"]["amount"]
let inBalance = userInfo["data"]["inBalance"]
```

I'm not sure if this is gonna work or not I didn't try it.. try this function for the notification properties:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {


    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    let message = userInfo["message"] as! String
    if message.isEmpty == true {

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge])
    }else {

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }



}
```

Comment: I get two push notifications at once.Second push comes with nil "message etc." there i need to convert in without .sound

Comment: sorry "amount" and "inBalance" doesn't work in my code

Comment: how about `let amount = userInfo["amount"]` ?

Answer (score 1):

*For Silent Notifications there are two criterions:*

1.) The payload's aps dictionary must include the content-available key with a value of 1.

2.) The payload's aps dictionary must not contain the alert, sound, or badge keys.

*example*

{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
    },
    "cusomtkey1" : "bar",
    "cusomtkey2" : 42
}